# Winexe from Ubuntu to Windows Server 2019 ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-access, windows-server-2019, winexe

When trying to run a command remotely on a Windows Server 2019 machine from a Ubuntu 16.04 machine using winexe:

```
winexe -U 'someusesr%thepas!#<sword' //34.86.123.123 "ipconfig"
```

the following error appears after some time of doing nothing:

> ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

TCP port 137 has already been opened (using Google Cloud Firewall) for the Windows Server 2019 system. What might be the problem here that is preventing this command from running remotely?

*Using Winexe v1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. Target system is a Windows Server 2019 running on Google Cloud*

Comment: how did you install winexe?